# Cómo validar en un Where con if en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, condiciones, select, where

espero puedan ayudarme:

Tengo la tabla Ejemplo, cuya estructura es:

```
CREATE TABLE EJEMPLO
(
ID INT,
MONEDA INT,
CANTIDAD INT
)
```

Contiene los siguientes registros:

[image: Registros de tabla Ejemplo]

Lo que requiero es:

Si la MONEDA es 0, que excluya la CANTIDAD de -10 a 10 (-11,-12.. y 11,12.. sería válido)

Si la MONEDA es 1, que excluya la CANTIDAD de -1 a 1 (-2,-3.. y 2,3.. sería válido)

Lo intente con un Where Case..

Algo como esto:

```
select * from EJEMPLO
where case when MONEDA=1 case when CANTIDAD 1 then  end
```

Pero no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo, aunque parece sencillo..

Básicamente lo que quiero es como meter un IF dentro del Where para que valide si es tal moneda me exluya el rango de valores mencionados arriba, algo como esto (sé que no puede ser así, pero lo escribo como si fuera pseudocódigo):

```
--Pseudocódigo:
select * from EJEMPLO
where
case when MONEDA = 1 then CANTIDAD not between -1 and 1 
case when MONEDA = 0 then CANTIDAD not between -10 and 10
```

De tal forma que los únicos registros que deberían aparecer son los del ID 7 al 10.

PD: No es tarea escolar, sólo hice esta tabla para adaptarla a mi caso real.

Answer (score 3):

Solo necesitas tener un poco de lógica.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Ejemplo
WHERE (moneda = 1 AND cantidad NOT BETWEEN -1 AND 1)
OR    (moneda = 0 AND cantidad NOT BETWEEN -10 AND 10);
```

Ahora, que también podrías usar algo más orientado a base de datos y usar una tabla o un [contructor con valores de tabla](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT e.*
FROM Ejemplo e
JOIN (VALUES( 1, -1, 1),
            (0, -10, 10)) m(moneda, limite_inf, limite_sup) 
                               ON e.moneda = m.moneda
                              AND e.cantidad NOT BETWEEN m.limite_inf AND m.limite sup;
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `NOT BETWEEN` y usar una condición para colocar los límites:

```
select *
from EJEMPLO
where CANTIDAD not between iif(MONEDA = 0, -10, -1) and iif(MONEDA = 0, 10, 1)
```